# MYSQL Triggers update table

Tags: mysql, triggers

I've never made trigger before.

I have two tables:

```
MOVIES TABLE
---------------------------------
movie_id  | movie_name | rating |
---------------------------------
|    1    | Inception  |   4    |
|    2    |  Memento   |   5    |
|    3    | Spiderman  |   3    |


RATING TABLE
-------------------------------
rating_id | mov_id | rating   |
-------------------------------
|    1    |    1     |   4    |
|    2    |    2     |   5    |
|    3    |    2     |   5    |
```

I want to update `MOVIES` TABLE's rating column after inserting data in RATING TABLE.
How is it possible to update that Column, with this data:

```
SELECT ROUND(AVG(rating),1) "Raiting" FROM `rating` WHERE mov_id = mov_id
```

Comment: Well, when it's the first time, most people google the syntax. Do this by googling "mysql create trigger". In the manual are examples too, you know? Then have a try. If you don't succeed, feel free to come back. Don't forget to post what you've tried and why it didn't work. Then we're glad to help.

Comment: I've tried and because of I failed, I posted here :| thanks anyway

Comment: Yes, then please show what you've tried. Not only is it easier then to understand what's the problem, it also spares us some work. Help others to help you ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
delimiter //
CREATE TRIGGER upd_rating AFTER INSERT ON rating
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
     INSERT INTO movies
     SET rating = (SELECT ROUND(AVG(rating.rating),1)
                   FROM rating
                   WHERE mov_id = NEW.mov_id)
     WHERE movie_id = NEW.mov_id;
END;//
delimiter ;
```